# Android Facebook login using a library

Tags: android, facebook

I have several Android apps I'm writing with similar functionality. All of them have to enable  Facebook login. I was thinking about implementing the Facebook login functionalty in a library and using it in each of the apps (with one FB API key).

Can this be done? does the FB API key correspond to the App signature (which probably means this CANNOT be done)?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, and is already handled in a few different existing libraries.

I know there are many, but one that I know that already implements this in AndroidQuery.  At a minumum, you can look at how they did their implementation to get a better idea of what is possible.  I am sure there are other libraries that do the same thing, this is the one I know about for sure:
http://code.google.com/p/android-query/  (check the documentation for the 'Authentication' section)